# Friend function not able to access member of class C++

Tags: c++, class, friend

I'm trying to overload the operator “<<“ as a friend function but for some reason it cannot access members of the class. Why isn't the friend function able to access **isEmpty()**, **count** and **call_DB[ ]** ?
This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class callRecord
{
public:
   string firstname;
   string lastname;
   string cell_number;
   int relays;
   int call_length;
   double net_cost;
   double tax_rate;
   double call_tax;
   double total_cost;
};

class callClass
{
public:

   bool isEmpty();
   friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, callClass &Org);

private:
   int count;
   int size;
   callRecord *call_DB;
};

bool callClass::isEmpty()
{
   if (count == 0)
   {
       return 1;
   }
   else
   {
       return 0;
   }
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, callClass &Org)
{
   if (isEmpty() == 1)
   {
       cout << "The array is empty" << endl;
   }
   else
   {
       out.setf(ios::showpoint);
       out.setf(ios::fixed);
       out.precision(2);

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
           out << setw(10) << call_DB[i].firstname << " ";
           out << setw(10) << call_DB[i].lastname << " ";
           out << call_DB[i].cell_number << "\t";
           out << call_DB[i].relays << "\t";
           out << call_DB[i].call_length << "\t";
           out << call_DB[i].net_cost << "\t";
           out << call_DB[i].tax_rate << "\t";
           out << call_DB[i].call_tax << "\t";
           out << call_DB[i].total_cost << endl;
       }
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Either make the operator part of your class (`callClass::operator<<`) or make it a free operator and call `Org::isEmpty()`.

Comment: They need to be invoked on `Org`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 2):

Your `operator<<` function is a global function and not a member of `callClass`.  To access those fields, you need to use `Org.call_DB`, `Org.count` and `Org.isEmpty();`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you did not "qualify" those members to an instance. You need to write

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, callClass &Org)
{
    if (Org.isEmpty() == 1)
//      ^^^^^
```

similary `Org.count` and `Org.call_DB` etc ..

Remember that your `operator<<` is a *global* function, not a *member* function. Otherwise you wouldn't have the need to declare it as friend in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't the friend function able to access isEmpty(), count and call_DB[ ] ?

Because you do not understand what "access" means. It does not mean that friend function becomes a method of the class, so you cannot implicitly use `this` as you trying to do, you should use `Org` argument:

```
out << setw(10) << Org.call_DB[i].firstname << " ";
```

same for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend function is not a member function so there is no 'this' available. Your operator code should looks like:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, callClass &Org)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
           out << Org.call_DB[i] << endl;
       }
   }
}
```

and then you must also provide an operator `<<` for `callRecord`.